# Build different Docker images based on Maven results (with Jenkins)

Tags: java, docker, maven, jenkins, jar

I have a Java application with quite some dependencies that I'd like to split into multiple Docker images:

- Core with Proxy (nginx), JVM and database drivers -> changes hardly
- Dependencies: all the Jar files my application depends on -> changes sometimes
- the application: one extra Jar -> changes daily or more (during development)

Something along these lines:

[image: Docker layers]

I know how to build these Docker images manually. I also can build a docker image in maven:

```xml
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${dockerfile-maven-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>push</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <dockerfile>src/main/docker/dockerfile</dockerfile>
                    <repository>myprivateregistry.io:5000/repourl</repository>
                    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <JAR_FILE>myapp.jar</JAR_FILE>
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I presume, that I can add the plugin twice to build the middle and the top layer?

However I would like to kick off the middle build only, and only if the content of `target/libs` that contains all the dependency Jars has changed (new Jars, new version of Jars, Jar removal)

How do I do that?

We are currently using Jenkins to run our builds (I would favour a "inside maven" solution).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with maven.
Maven does not keep track which modules have been built in the past, and thus it cannot know which libs may habe been altered. There are plugins like maven-compiler-plugin which take the timestamp of source files and compare with the class files to skip compilation but I doubt there is a plugin which can do what you require.

However, simply always built both images as you suggested. Just built the dependency image first, then your app image. Docker is pretty good at caching layers. That means in case that your libs haven't changed it just retrieves the image from the cache. Otherwise it will built a new image. IMPORTANT: That will only work if the docker daemon on your Jenkins is always the same. If you have a clustered Jenkins, there will be lots of cache misses. But it will still work in general, yet any speed up is lost.

Comment: For Jenkins there is [Job Cacher](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/jobcacher/)

Comment: So I need to look at Jenkins. Job cacher might not do the trick since mvn clean will nuke the files

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Google thought about that problem and created a Maven plugin for that. The [Google](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib) do exactly that.

The upside: it takes automatic care of all layers:

- Resources
- Dependencies
- Code

The downside: it doesn't use docker files, but defines the image completely in the [Maven POM](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/examples/helloworld/pom.xml)

A sample would look like that:

```xml
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${jib.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <from>
                                <image>some.base.image:latest</image>
                            </from>
                            <to>
                                <image>destination.image</image>
                                <tags>${project.version}</tags>
                            </to>
                            <extraDirectories>
                                <paths>
                                    <path>
                                        <from>src/main/docker/scripts</from>
                                        <into>/opt/myapp/scripts</into>
                                    </path>
                                </paths>
                                <permissions>
                                    <permission>
                                        <file>/opt/shutdown_script</file>
                                        <mode>555</mode>
                                    </permission>
                                    <permission>
                                        <file>/opt/startup_script</file>
                                        <mode>555</mode>
                                    </permission>
                                </permissions>
                            </extraDirectories>
                            <container>
                                <creationTime>USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP</creationTime>
                                <appRoot>/opt/myapp</appRoot>
                                <entrypoint>
                                    <entry>/opt/myapp/entry_point.sh</entry>
                                </entrypoint>
                                <ports>
                                    <port>80</port>
                                    <port>389</port>
                                    <port>8880</port>
                                    <port>8889</port>
                                    <port>8890</port>
                                </ports>
                                <user>appuser</user>
                                <volumes>
                                    <volume>/local/data</volume>
                                </volumes>
                            </container>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>dockerBuild</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

Seems to fit my needs